# Serverless Framework: Request must be smaller than 69905067 bytes for the UpdateFunctionCode operation

Tags: serverless-framework

I am using package uploading zipped file like

```
frameworkVersion: "=1.27.3"

service: recipes

provider:
  name: aws
  endpointType: REGIONAL
  runtime: python3.6
  stage: dev
  region: eu-central-1
  memorySize: 512
  deploymentBucket:
    name: dfki-meta
  versionFunctions: false
  stackTags:
    Project: DFKIAPP
  # Allows updates to all resources except deleting/replacing EC2 instances
  stackPolicy:
    - Effect: Allow
      Principal: "*"
      Action: "Update:*"
      Resource: "*"
    - Effect: Deny
      Principal: "*"
      Action:
        - Update: Replace
        - Update: Delete
      Resource: "*"
      Condition:
        StringEquals:
          ResourceType:
            - AWS::EC2::Instance
  # Access to RDS and S3 Bucket
  iamRoleStatements:
    -  Effect: "Allow"
       Action: "s3:ListBucket"
       Resource: "*"


package:
  individually: true

functions:
#  get_recipes:
#    handler: handler.get_recipes
#    module: recipes_crud
#    package:
#      individually: true
#    timeout: 30
#    events:
#      - http:
#          path: recipes
#          method: get
#          request:
#            parameters:
#              querystring:
#                persona: true

  get_recommendation:
    handler: handler.get_recommendation
    module: recipes_ml
    package:
      artifact: zipped_dir.zip
    timeout: 30
    events:
      - http:
          path: recipes/{id}
          method: get
          request:
            parameters:
              paths:
                id: true
              querystring:
                schaerfe_def: true
                saettig_def: true
                erfahrung_def: true
                schaerfe_wunsch: true
                saettig_wunsch: true
                erfahrung_wunsch: true
                gericht_wunsch: true
                stimmung_wunsch: true
```

Can not understand this error, isn't 52.18 under 69905067 bytes ?

```
(node:50928) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
Serverless: Packaging function: get_recommendation...
Serverless: Uploading function: get_recommendation (52.18 MB)...

  Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

  Request must be smaller than 69905067 bytes for the UpdateFunctionCode operation

  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com

  Your Environment Information -----------------------------
     OS:                     darwin
     Node Version:           10.1.0
     Serverless Version:     1.27.3
```

Comment: If you remove your stack and redeploy it works. Deploying a single oversized function doesn't work. I'm still tryng to understand why

Answer (score 13):

This seems to be an issue only while uploading individual lambda function using serverless but if you don't give --function parameter and deploy full stack then it works fine!!!

Answer (score 7):

The package size should be lower than 50MB according to the docs 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html
[image]

from [this blog post](https://hackernoon.com/exploring-the-aws-lambda-deployment-limits-9a8384b0bec3)

> The 20 MB addition presumably is there there to account for request
>   overhead involved with the AWS API (e.g. base64 encoding of the zip
>   file data). So far the 50 MB limit holds true-ish. But, we’re not
>   defeated yet.

Comment: this is strange. my zipped lambda package is 66 MB. If I try to update the function using the CLI, I get this error. But if I upload it to S3, I can update the function on the AWS console by providing the file path on S3.

Comment: that's really interesting information, I never actually tried that. But for sure you would hit a limit I would say.

Comment: Yes, I still hit the limit either way if the unzipped data is > 250 MB. But on the CLI, it doesn't let me update the function if the zip is > 50 MB even though unzipped is < 250 MB.

Answer (score 0):

If need to update only config, should use this
--update-config or -u Pushes ONLY Lambda-level configuration changes e.g. handler, timeout or memorySize

```
serverless deploy function -f functionName --update-config
```